# How to take multiple value for strongly typed data model list in ASP.NET-MVC-5 inside razor code

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, strongly-typed-view

I have strongly typed view model and I need to take multiple records for "List" from user for strongly typed list. I am struggling to achieve this in razor code. This is [httpget] method.

### View Model

```
public class AccommodationApplicationViewModel
{
    public AccommodationApplicationViewModel() 
    {
        _RentingApplicationModel = new PropertyRentingApplication();
        _PropertyRentingPriceModel = new List<PropertyRentingPrice>();
        _AdditionalTenantModel = new List<AdditionalTenant>();
        _StudentLimitedInfoModel = new List<StudentLimitedInfo>();
    }

    public PropertyRentingApplication _RentingApplicationModel { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyRentingPrice> _PropertyRentingPriceModel { get; set; }
    public List<AdditionalTenant> _AdditionalTenantModel { get; set; }
    public List<StudentLimitedInfo> _StudentLimitedInfoModel { get; set; }

}
```

### Razor code

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._StudentLimitedInfoModel[0].StudentNumber_UWLID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            //@Html.EditorFor(model => model._StudentLimitedInfoModel[0].StudentNumber_UWLID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._StudentLimitedInfoModel[0].StudentNumber_UWLID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

I get error in following line

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model._StudentLimitedInfoModel[0].StudentNumber_UWLID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

The error is:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: What error are you getting. And your only attempting to render elements for the first item. Are you wanting to edit all items in the collection?

Comment: no I need to take values from user !!!

Comment: i get following error; Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Then `_StudentLimitedInfoModel` is an empty list - it contains no items! In any case, using a hardcoded indexer will not work correctly anyway. Use a `for` loop - `for(int i = 0; i < Model._StudentLimitedInfoModel.Count; i++) { @Html.EditorFor(m=> m._StudentLimitedInfoModel[i].StudentNumber_UWLID, ....) etc }`

Comment: If you're only `new`ing your collections and not populating them with any real data, why wouldn't an exception get thrown?

Comment: @toxic try to check if collection really have any data before using index like [0]

Comment: i guess am using wrong apprach as I am expecting to enter data from user here not displaying out...

Comment: @toxic, From you last comment, it appears you want to dynamically add new items to your collection. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) gives some options, and [this article](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) explains using the `BeginCollectionItem` helper in more depth

Answer (score 0):

You can take one of two approaches with this. If there's a fixed number of items for the list, you can simply initialize it with the appropriate number of instances. For example:

```
_PropertyRentingPriceModel = new List<PropertyRentingPrice>
{
    new PropertyRentingPrice(),
    new PropertyRentingPrice(),
    new PropertyRentingPrice()
};
```

That would give you three items. Then, in your view:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model._PropertyRentingPriceModel.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m._PropertyRentingPriceModel[i].Foo)
}
```

If the items are more fluid, or the user needs to be able to add or remove items at will, you'll need a JavaScript solution, which will involve creating the inputs and assigning them the appropriate names manually. For this, I'd recommend using some sort of data binding library with support for templates, such as Knockout or Angular. Doing so will make your life *much* easier. When building your JavaScript template, you just need to keep in mind the convention for collection input names that the modelbinder will expect to see in your POST request: `CollectionProperty[Index].Property`. For example, you input would need to look something like:

```
<input type="text" name="_PropertyRentingPriceModel[0].Foo" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar and ended up using an article I found [here](http://ivanz.com/2011/06/16/editing-variable-length-reorderable-collections-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1/) to do it. I'd post my implementation but I had to customize it enough that it would just confuse what you're looking for.